# SQLPlus Report Formatting

Tags: sqlplus

I need to generate an Excel based on a sql query. The Issue is when I open the Excel the DTIME does not show the seconds unless I format the cell in Excel. Also the Test_ID is 14 Digits and shows as exponential form in Excel.

I have looked through so many forums and could not find a solution yet. Any help/advise will be greatly appreciated.

```
SET LINESIZE 32767;
SET PAGESIZE 32767;
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET MARKUP HTML ON SPOOL ON
SPOOL D:\TEST.xls;
Select  
        TO_CHAR(DTIME, 'MM/DD/RRRR HH:MI:SS AM') DTIME,
        (TEST_ID ||'                        ') AS TEST_ID,
        From
            TEST_DETAILS enqd
Where
            enqd.RUN_DATE >= sysdate - 15/1440
Order By
            enqd.RUN_DATE
/
spool off;
exit;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting that field from Number to Text is an option.